# Microsoft Excel 2010 Lookup between 2 worksheets

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula, worksheet

I have 2 worksheets in Excel, and I’d like to create a column in the first worksheet that returns a value based on whether a column of Worksheet 1 exists in a column in Worksheet 2.  For example, the first worksheet, ‘FavoriteColors’:

```
Name    |  FavoriteColor

John    |   Blue

Betty   |  Green

Joe     |  Blue

Fred    |  Yellow

Beth    |  Blue
```

The second worksheet is called ‘BlueFans’  and is as follows:

```
Name

John

Betty

Beth
```

I want to add a column to the FavoriteColors worksheet, using a function that looks up to see if the Name exists in the second worksheet BlueFans, and returns a respective value, as follows:

```
Name    |   FavoriteColor    |  Is_it_blue

John    |   Blue             |  Yes

Betty   |   Green            |  No

Joe     |   Blue             |  Yes

Fred    |  Yellow            |  No

Beth    |   Blue             |  Yes
```

I have to leverage the second worksheet.  I can’t simply use a function that uses the logic:  “If favorite color = blue then ‘yes’ else ‘no’.  Any assistance would be appreciated

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2,BlueFans!A:A,0),"NO","YES")
```

Assuming your data in `BlueFans` is in Column A.
And your Data in `FavoriteColors` are in Column A and B starting in 2n row.
Put formula in `C2`.
Hope this is close to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you mean by **leverage** the second worksheet.  But a formula on Sheet1 that will return Yes or No, depending on whether the Name in Column A exists on BlueFans would be:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(BlueFans!$A$1:$A$100,A2),"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that `COUNTIF` is slower in this case than `MATCH` (it needs to check the whole range, while `MATCH` exits as soon as there's a match and so doesn't need to check the whole range).

Comment: That's true.  On my machine the difference is on the order of 1/10,000th of a second, so I suppose with a great number of repetitive calculations, the difference might be noticeable.